# Fälschen oder verfälschen?

Tags: difference, word-choice, usage

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *fälschen* und *verfälschen*?

Ist etwa *verfälschen* intensiver als *fälschen*?

Was ist zum Beispiel richtig (oder richtiger)?

> - Er hat meine Unterschrift gefälscht.
> - Er hat meine Unterschrift verfälscht.

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch? Du hast doch ein Wörterbuch erst bemüht, oder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

beide Sätze haben eine komplett unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

> Er hat meine Unterschrift gefälscht

bedeutet: Er hat selbst die Unterschrift geschrieben / mit einem Kopierer kopiert / reproduziert.

> Er hat meine Unterschrift verfälscht

bedeutet: Ich habe etwas unterschrieben, und der andere hat diese Unterschrift durch hinzufügen oder weglöschen von Strichen / Bestandteilen abgeändert.

Für Unterschriften ist das etwas, was ich noch nie gehört habe, weil es keinen Sinn ergibt, eine Unterschrift eines anderen abzuändern, es sei denn, man möchte sie ungültig machen.

Order um es allgemeiner zu machen: Eine Fälschung ist eine (illegale) Kopie des Originals, eine Verfälschung die Veränderung des Originals selbst.

Comment: Viel besser erklärt als ich. +1

Answer (score 3):

*Fälschen* bezieht sich meistens darauf, dass etwas als ein Original oder eben das Echte ausgegeben wird.

> "Diese 'Marke-Einfügen'-Schuhe  wurden gefälscht. Sie sind keine originalen Markenschuhe."

Eine "Unterschrift *verfälschen*" ist eigentlich kein gutes Beispiel. Es würde implizieren, dass die Unterschrift "bearbeitet" wurde.

Etwas *verfälschen* wird meistens in anderem Kontext genutzt, z.B.

> "Das Ergebnis der Wahl wurde verfälscht".
>
> "Das Statistikergebnis wurde verfälscht." - durch falsche "Zielgruppe" o.Ä.

Wobei man bei den beiden Bespielen auch schreiben kann:

> "Das Ergebnis der Wahl wurde gefälscht." - Es wurde gar nicht ausgezählt oder es wurden die Stimmen falsch gezählt/eingeordnet.

Aber damit wäre das Ergebnis eben auch *ver*fälscht.

Ich hoffe, das hilft irgendwie weiter, das Ganze zu verstehen ... Eventuell helfen dir diese Informationen schon ein wenig.